# VueJS 3: update value and avoid watch

Tags: javascript, vue.js, watch

I am coding a table with pagination component, and I use multiple v-model and `watch` on these variables to fetch the data.
When `perPage` is updated, I want to reset `page` to 1. So I did it in my `watch` method but of course, `watch` is triggered twice (for `perPage` and then `page`).

Is it possible to update the variable and disable watch at this moment ?

Here is my current code:

```html
<script setup lang="ts">

const sort = ref(route.query.sort || 'created_at')
const filters = ref(route.query.filters || {})
const page = ref(route.query.page ? parseInt(route.query.page.toString()) : 1)
const perPage = ref(route.query.per_page ? parseInt(route.query.per_page.toString()) : 10)

watch([sort, filters, page, perPage], ([oldSort, oldFilters, oldPage, oldPerPage], [newSort, newFilters, newPage, newPerPage]) => {
  if (oldPerPage !== newPerPage)
    page.value = 1

  fetchItems()

  router.push({
    query: {
      ...route.query,
      sort: sort.value,
      // filters: filters.value,
      page: page.value,
      per_page: perPage.value,
    },
  })
})

async function fetchItems() {
  items.value = await userApi.list({
    filters: toRaw(filters.value),
    sort: sort.value,
    page: page.value,
    perPage: perPage.value,
  })
}
</script>

<template>
    <CTable
      :pagination-enabled="true"
      v-model:sort="sort"
      v-model:page="page"
      v-model:per-page="perPage"
      :total-items="items.meta.total"
      :total-pages="items.meta.last_page"
    />
</template>
```

The only workaround I found is to return when I reset `page`:

```js
watch(..., () => {
  if (oldPerPage !== newPerPage) {
    page.value = 1
    return
  }

  fetchItems()

  ...
})
```

It is working in my case but for some another cases I would like to update without trigger the watch method.

Thanks!

Comment: `working in my case but for some another cases` - if it works for you, do you really care about "another cases" that you haven't even shown the code for?

Comment: A watcher is a proper way to do this. "I would like to update without trigger the watch method" - why? Btw watcher signature is wrong, `newSort`, etc params come first

Comment: @JaromandaX You're right, but I have other cases in some components where I want to use `watch` conditionally, and I want to write my code with the same "style" everywhere.

Comment: @EstusFlask Indeed args where in the wrong order, thank you for noticing that! In my example, watch is triggered twice: when `perPage` is updated and then when `page` is updated. and because I reset `page` when `perPage` is updated, I want to update `page` and disable watch at this specific time.

Comment: This is XY problem. Since you have problems with dupe triggers, that's what needs to be addressed. Unless you don't want to ditch v-model and handle data yourself, watchers are a way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for all your answers, I finally found what I was looking for using [VueUse - watchIgnorable](https://vueuse.org/shared/watchignorable/):

```js
const { stop, ignoreUpdates } = watchIgnorable(page, (value) => {
  fetchItems()
})

watch(perPage, (newPerPage, oldPerPage) => {
  if (newPerPage !== oldPerPage) {
    ignoreUpdates(() => {
      page.value = 1
    })
  }

  fetchItems()
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Create another watcher for `perPage` :

```js
watch([sort, filters, page, perPage], ([oldSort, oldFilters, oldPage, oldPerPage], [newSort, newFilters, newPage, newPerPage]) => {

  fetchItems()

  router.push({
    query: {
      ...route.query,
      sort: sort.value,
      // filters: filters.value,
      page: page.value,
      per_page: perPage.value,
    },
  })
})

watch(perPage, (newPerPage,oldPerPage ) => {
  if (oldPerPage !== newPerPage)
    page.value = 1
})
```

It's recommended to create watch for a single property separately to avoid unnecessarily updates and conflicts. For the first watch try to replace it with `watchEffect` like since you're not using the old/new value:

```js
watchEffect(() => {
  fetchItems()
  router.push({
    query: {
      ...route.query,
      sort: sort.value,
      // filters: filters.value,
      page: page.value,
      per_page: perPage.value,
    },
  })
})
```

Comment: `if (oldPerPage !== newPerPage)` is unnecessary. May cause problems with the first watcher being triggered twice because of changes in page. It likely needs to be debounced in this case

Comment: `watchEffect` is called twice every time I update a value. If you have an idea why you're welcome. For now I stay with one `watch` per property as you recommended.

Comment: Ok , so keep using one watch per property

Answer (score 0):

Considering that the state is changed through `v-model`, it needs to be observed with a watcher.

In order to avoid a watcher to be triggered multiple times, it should implement additional conditions like shown in the question, but it also needs to not skip an update when `page` is already `1`, this won't result in additional update:

```
  if (oldPerPage !== newPerPage) {
    page.value = 1

    if (newPage !== 1)
      return
  }
```

Otherwise there need to be multiple watchers, like [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73669893/3731501) suggests. In case a watcher that causes asynchronous side effects (`fetchItems`) shouldn't be triggered more than it needs, and there are other causes for this to happen besides `perPage`, it can be debounced, e.g.:

```
watch(perPage, () => {
  page.value = 1
});

watch([sort, filters, page, perPage], debounce(() => {
  fetchItems()
  ...
}, 100));
```